# unable to resolve jsonSlurper even when its imported and groovy package added to gradle.build

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, import

Im trying groovy project and I cant get it running with trying jsonSlurper. Not sure why.
The dependency for groovy is added and import.groovy.json.* is imported.

gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy:4.0.2'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}
```

Error:
Unable to resolve class JsonSlurper

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-json:4.0.2'
```

Might as well update to 4.0.11 as well whilst you're there

Comment: why doesnt intellij/gradle offer me the option to add it when it sees Im using it?